# How to edit the function of the close button on MAUI Blazor Hybrid

Tags: button, blazor, maui, hybrid

I am working on an application written in MAUI Blazor.
I would like that after click on the red button "Close", to bring up the message "Are you sure you want to close the application?".
How to modify the function of the close system button on Windows?
I tried used OnClosed event but I don't know how to use it correctly.

```
#if WINDOWS
            events.AddWindows(wndLifeCycleBuilder =>
            {
                wndLifeCycleBuilder.OnClosed((window, args) => LogEvent("OnClosed"));

                wndLifeCycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated(window =>
                {
                    //Set size and center on screen using WinUIEx extension method
                    window.CenterOnScreen(400, 750);
                    window.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = true;
                });
            });

#endif
```

[image: Close button]

I mean this button.

Comment: `OnClosed` happens too late. Use `OnClosing`. To not close, use `CancelEventArgs.Cancel`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs?view=net-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=windowsdesktop-6.0. (If you get this to work, add `Your Answer` below, showing the working code.)

Comment: But I can't see OnClosing in MAUI. I have only Created, Deactivated, Destroying and this only allow to EventArgs.

Comment: Inside of `#if Windows` you write `Windows Desktop App` code (aka `WinUI 3`), not Maui code. I am referring to the code you show `wndLifeCycleBuilder.OnClosed`. Change to `wndLifeCycleBuilder.OnClosing`. `LogEvent` declaration will also need to be inside `#if Windows`, later in file.

Comment: "OnClosing" doesn't exists :( wndLifeCycleBuilder is IWindowsLifeCycleBuilder type. I don't have idea how to catch onclosing event.

Comment: Ok. I think you need [Window.OnClosing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.onclosing?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), which is Windows-specific. Sounds like it is not supported by the "builder". See if you can find out how to get at the `Window` object (the native Windows one, not the cross-platform Maui one), inside `#if Windows`. After the app builder has been run. Maybe has to be later in code, after window appears on screen. There must be some way to make Windows API calls on that window. Post a new question about that, or post an issue at "github maui issues".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
#if WINDOWS
events.AddWindows(windowsLifecycleBuilder =>
{
    windowsLifecycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated(window =>
    {
        //we need this to use Microsoft.UI.Windowing functions for our window
        var handle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
        var id = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(handle);
        var appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(id);

        //and here it is
        appWindow.Closing += async (s, e) => 
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            bool result = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(
                "Alert title", 
                "You sure want to close app?", 
                "Yes", 
                "Cancel");

            if (result)
            {
                App.Current.Quit();
            }
        };
    });
});
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Great! this works for a regular visual studio MAUI app too!

In App.xaml.cs:

```
    protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
    {
        Window window = base.CreateWindow(activationState);

#if WINDOWS
        window.Created += (s, e) =>
        {

            //we need this to use Microsoft.UI.Windowing functions for our window
            var handle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window.Handler.PlatformView);
            var id = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(handle);
            var appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(id);

            //and here it is
            appWindow.Closing += async (s, e) =>
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                bool result = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(
                    "Alert title",
                    "You sure want to close app?",
                    "Yes",
                    "Cancel");

                if (result)
                {
                    App.Current.Quit();
                }
            };
        };
#endif
        return window;
    }
```